# bit field issue in visual c++

Tags: c++, struct

I want to use this struct in visual c++:

```
struct iphdr
{
    unsigned int ihl:4;
    unsigned int version:4;

    u_int8_t tos;
    u_int16_t tot_len;
    u_int16_t id;
    u_int16_t frag_off;
    u_int8_t ttl;
    u_int8_t protocol;
    u_int16_t check;
    struct in_addr ip_src;
    struct in_addr ip_dst;

};
```

but when debugging I found `sizeof(struct iphdr) = 24`, which expected to be `20`
And it is strange that when I replace `ihl` and `version` with a `char`, `sizeof(struct iphdr) = 20`

Comment: are you compiling on 32 bit or on 64 bit compiler?

Comment: Seems like it's more than just the usual struct alignment/padding thing.

Comment: @izomorphius no, it's a 32bit compiler and i'm using vc++ 2008

Comment: Do you have `#pragma pack(1)` in source code, or the equivalent compiler option to pack the structure?

Comment: @wallyk yes, i have applyed it to another struct, but it makes no difference when I place this struct before any #progma pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitfields `ihl` and `version` will be placed in an `unsigned int` field (despite the fact that they would fit into a character). Hence, the field `tos` will be placed at offset 4, and `tot_length` at offset 6, due to padding.